# How to add indexing to maketable queries in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access, indexing, create-table

So I work with a remote data source that refreshes daily, so I have to run a few make table queries to translate/process the most up to date snapshot into tables.

However I don't see any clear way to add indexing. Right now what I am doing is I use one query to pull from the data source and manipulate it (call the result of this SourceQuery). And then in my maketable query I'll do:

```
SELECT SourceQuery.* INTO [Results Table] IN '\\path\to\dest\myDatabase.mdb' FROM SourceQuery;
```

But the resulting table has "No" in the index field for everything.

How can I modify the queries to add indexing to fields that are commonly used in joins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write `SELECT INTO` statement, the structure of the new table is defined by the attributes of the expressions in the select list, so you won't be able to get the indexes of the source table this way.

you should write create index in your query
`CREATE INDEX NewIndex ON [Results Table] (field1, field2)`

Comment: In your example, does that create an index on two fields at once, or one index per field?

Comment: it creates index on two fields combined.

Comment: `you should write create index in your query` this will need to be a separate query because Access can't execute two statements at once.

Comment: @Brad Can you elaborate on how, specifically?

Comment: @TedoG. What if I want to write indexes only for singular fields? For example I often join on FieldA or FieldB, or both at the same time, so I think I'd need three indexes? One for A, B, and then A+B? Or does it not work like that?

Comment: depending on how you're executing this you will need to either make a new Query object (Create > Query Design > Data Definition > Paste this in> Save new query) then run after your `Select Into` query. Or if you are using `CurrentDb.Execute` then make this a second call to `CurrentDb.Execute`

Comment: Is there a difference between CurrentDb.execute and docmd.openquery? I currently use an adodb.recordset to iterate over a table of maketable query names, and then I use docmd.openquery to run each query. Anyways I guess I'd just add the index queries to this process.

Comment: @KaliMa `Docmd.OpenQuery` is supposed to be for opening a select query though it will open Insert/update/deletes as well. The disadvantage is you'll get those pop-ups saying "you are about to run a make table query" and "you are about to add XX records. are you sure you want to?". Which  you can either click through or set `DoCmd.SetWarnings` to false. BUT setting `DoCmd.SetWarnings` is one of the biggest sources of hidden errors in Access and highly recommended against. ...

Comment: @KaliMa `CurrentDb.Execute` has none of those pitfalls and many benefits. You have access to the `CurrentDb.RecordsAffected` property for one. But even better may be to execute actual `QueryDef` objects which have even more granular control over `CurrentDb.execute` such as parameters. (Sorry Tedo G. for jumping on your answer...)

Comment: Do I have to make separate indexes for all use cases? (see above comment)